# Modal Dialog Component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I have a separate component created to be my modal. Its attached to my li and hidden, I am trying to click on the profile icon and when I click to open the modal. So far, every once in a while the modal will work when I first save, but if I refresh I get an error say "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'showModal') ". My only thought is that I am using a querySelector to reach my Modal Component. But I am at a loss for the time being on how to get this to work.

Heres my Modal Component.

```
export default function Modal() {
  return (
    <dialog data-modal>
      <form method="dialog">
        <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <br />
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="number" placeholder="Phone Number" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Address" />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </dialog>
  );
}
```

Heres my nav bar and how I am trying to reference the Modal:

```
import TopBar from "./IntroTopBar";
import Promo from "./promo/PromoBar";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "./ProfileModal";

const modal = document.querySelector("[data-modal]");

function modalOpen() {
  modal.showModal();
}
```

Here is my nav bar where I have my Modal linked into my li:

```
export default function NavBar() {
return (
    <div className="nav-container">
      <TopBar />
      <div className="nav-links">
        <ul className="links">
          <li className="page-name">
            <Link to="/">Yummy-Delights</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="coffee">Coffee</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="fresh-bakes">Fresh-Bakes</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="diy">DIY</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul className="data-field">
          <li>
            <input placeholder="Search..."></input>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i className="bi bi-basket"></i>
          </li>
          <li>
            **<i onClick={modalOpen} className="bi bi-person-circle"></i>**
          </li>
          <li>
            <i className="bi bi-translate"></i>
          </li>
          <li>
            **<Modal />**
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <Promo />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried using querySelector, but I get the typeError. I also tried using useRef but got an error saying I could not use Ref in a function.